# Inheritance from Both NSViewController and NSImageView (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, inheritance, nsviewcontroller, nsimageview

How should I approach the situation of having to inherit from both NSViewController and NSImageView in the same project? Thank's!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "In the same project". If you mean you want a single class to inherit from NSViewController and NSImageView, you can't. Neither Swift, nor Objective-C allow multiple inheritance.

Comment: By "in the same project" I mean that I have a class that inherits, for example from NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate and it should also inherit from NSImageView. Adding the last class to my list of "parent" classes, produces an error, since I also inherit from NSViewController. I need to override some functions included in the NSImageView class and, since I do not have a Delegate for NSImageView, I am stuck...

Comment: Composition over inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Neither Swift nor Objective-C support multiple inheritance in the way you seem to require.

The usual adage is *composition over inheritance* meaning that rather than have a class inherit from every class that it needs to interact with, you could compose your class from objects that are able to handle that interaction.

So rather than inherit from `NSViewController` and `NSImageView` you can have your view controller subclass have a property which is an object that is an `NSImageView` subclass.